# Cardio meter animation in Android

Tags: java, android, animation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cardio graph for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041190/cardio-graph-for-android)

I want to develop cardiometer graph in Android, just like this image:

[image]

Can anyone help with any idea how to create this animation?

Comment: i have use LineDraw or DrawPath method on Canvas,  But this is Draw like Static Line, this will not give animation type Draw

Comment: @George Stocker , Hey If You Think this Question is Duplicated then Give me Perfect Anser of this Animation Question, I Need Sample Code for Working this Animation as Continues Sequence. I Hope u Give Perfect Code as Working Condition...

Comment: Help Full Site:  http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

You can show the progressive graph using frame sequence. And to show the needle, you can set the X and Y co-ordinate of the needle.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer ? Also post code if you have ?

Comment: what I mean to say is to consider X,Y co-ordinates of your device and then use LINEDRAW method in progressive menor to draw chart like the one shown in image.. other is to use Sprites and create chart like effects.

Comment: it's ok. we understand. he he he..!